# Do I need all the extras working with Laravel projects?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I installed XAMPP and Laravel on Windows 10. I found a "Hello world" tutorial and got it to work. I even think the migration worked. Now onto creating a real project and learning Laravel as I go. If I follow Laravel documentation, it tells me to install many other "things" such as Composer, WSL2, SAIL, etc. As usual, I follow the official documentation, yet nothing works. for WSL2, I chose openSUSE as a companion.

I got as far as creating a project, but I get a prompt for the root password at the end of the install. When I type the password, nothing happens. I have to CRTL+C out of the script. And as you can guess, I can't follow along anymore.

Why does my "Hello world" example, copied from Joe Schmoe's code, work, but the official docs tell me to install more companions? Is WSL2, SAIL necessary, and Composer essential? Will I run into dead ends during my project? Many years ago, I used to use Kohana, XAMPP, and Mustache. Things have changed quite a bit.

Comment: Composer isn't strictly necessary, but it does make it easier to upgrade the Laravel code as well as install and update packages that you may need. I haven't heard of the others.

Comment: I'm not sure about SAIL, but Composer has been really nice to use. I would say WSL2 *could* be nice once it's configured. In my experience, setting up Laravel Homestead/WSL2 is a total nightmare. It might be because I don't know enough about virtual machines and this is actually easy with more experience, but windows 10 professional has hyper-v which always seems to throw a wrench in the system when I try to do anything needing virtual machines. Especially if I try to disable hyper-v and use a different VM.

Comment: Sail is just a wrapper for docker. (I'd recommend to use docker, as you can set up and change php versions pretty fast, and stuff.)
If you have php and mysql already installed (and that's the reason if you have xampp running), just use the composer install method: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#installation-via-composer

Answer (score 1):

Thank you.
I recreated the project only using composer from windows prompt.  I was getting confused with all the options as a newbie. I was trying to run commands using conflicting methods.
For now I will just use composer without running it through the Linux Virtual Machine WSL2.  Fingers crossed....